# Firebase DatabaseReference filter data with query

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For example, I have this tree:

[image]

How to use query to get for example just the "meeting_1" by the user?

I tried this code (The names just for this example):

```
        final DatabaseReference mDatabase =  getDatabaseReference(ConstantNames.MEETINGS_PATH).child ( TeamID );
    Query query = mDatabase.orderByChild("PublicTo").equalTo("User_1");
```

This code not working. The value of DataSnapshot is "null"

Comment: The data structure you have makes it easy to find all users for a specific meeting. It does not however make it easy to find all meetings for a specific user. To allow that you'll need to add a similar-but-inverted data structure that maps from a user ID to their list of meetings. For more on this see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to access meeting 1 then you can only access that child which is meeting 1

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseReference = database.getReference("CupShupRooftop/Promos");
```

For example in the above code i am accessing promos which is child of cupshuprooftop
So in your case you can do

```
  db.getrefence("team id"/"meeting 1")
```

Comment: My goal is to eventually get all published meetings to same user. That is, to filter out from the data the meetings that are not intended for that user.